# Uploading video to YouTube by emailing to mobile upload address?

Tags: youtube, youtube-api

YouTube has this feature of upload videos to account by emailing them to your *mobile upload address* like `stxxxxwiicv@m.youtube.com`.I am using this feature to upload videos to my account.I can set the **Title** and **description** of the video while emailing, for this I just need to specify `Email Subject for video Title` and `Email message for video description`.My problem is that I would like to set the `keywords field` of the video as well while emailing the video.I am unable to find any way to specify the Keywords for mobile uploads.If thr is any official link for all this information then please provide me.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation for mobile uploads can be found at http://support.google.com/youtube/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=57407 and http://support.google.com/youtube/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=1110304

You can't add keywords from the email form, but you can log into YouTube from your phone's browser and add them there.

I also recommend you look into using one of YouTube's mobile apps if you have a phone that supports it.

https://itunes.apple.com/app/youtube/id544007664

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.youtube&hl=en

If you are just trying to automate the upload process please try out the YouTube Data API. https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos

Comment: But i wanted to automate this process, instead to manually logging in and updating keywords..

Comment: If you want to automate uploads you should use the youtube data apis https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos

Comment: yeah i know we can do using that....but thought thr would be some other way for specifying keywords...THanks